# How to change modified On/ Created on date of all email activities in MSCRM using SQL

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

We have MS CRM 2013 on-premise.
We had to update email id of all our previous email activities and in doing so all the activities have got updated with the new modified on and sent date.
Now the problem is whenever we see the activities on first page it is by default sorted by modified on date.
Is there any script(SQL) with which we can change the modified on/ Sent date of all the email activities.

Comment: You're probably better off sorting by something different.  I would stay away from trying to modify the created on/modified on fields as you're either venturing into unsupported territory (if you use sql scripts) or you will find odd behavior (if you try to use the OOB override created on).  On another note - how can you update the id of any record? that is the primary key and it shouldn't be possible to change it once its set.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here, you might find a solution to your problem:
http://www.magnetismsolutions.com/blog/vincentzhong/2012/08/15/how_to_modify_the_created_on_value_of_dynamics_crm_2011_part_1

I would also say, that modifying created on date using SQL is possible, but unsupported and I would really discourage you from doing that.